# Reordering the rows of a table using pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

I have a table in a file called `dummy.txt` which contains the following data:

```
value1  value2  value3
1   11  2.13652246624232
2   12  0.513442717554625
3   13  1.69712766271722
4   14  -1.57360405275275
5   15  0.784061900065905
```

I can print the table via

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  col sep=tab, 
  columns={value2,value1} 
  ]{dummy.txt}
```

Is there a similarly easy way to select the order and the actual selection for the rows, as there is for the columns?

I had a look at the manual, and the only thing which came close was the `row predicate` argument, which seemed a bit too powerful for my goal of selecting row number 2,3 and 5. And I don't know how to work with logical predicates in TeX.

Comment: What is the order you want to achieve?

Comment: @percusse: As this is just an example table, I guess that 5, 2, 3  would serve as a good example for my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Reordering" sounds a lot like sorting. In fact, you can sort the table according to your desired order - you only need a further (temporary) column with the order values. Of course, sorting does not filter. But you can easily use `skip rows between index` to filter the sorted result since the unwanted entries can easily be sorted to the end:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  columns={value2,value1},
  sort,sort key=sort order,
  create on use/sort order/.style={
    create col/set list={100,1,2,100,0},
  },
  skip rows between index={3}{100},
  ]{
value1  value2  value3
1   11  2.13652246624232
2   12  0.513442717554625
3   13  1.69712766271722
4   14  -1.57360405275275
5   15  0.784061900065905
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

this code sorts according to the values in column `sort order`. This column does not exist, it will be created according to the `create on use/sort order` specification -- and that contains an explicit list of 5 values, one for each row. The row with value1=5 receives 0, the row with value1=2 receives 1, and the row with value1=3 receives 2 - all other ones get an 100. You can easily add `columns={value2,value1,sort order}` to see the results.

You mention that this is "just an example table". If you have a huge table, this `create on use` stuff can easily become tedious. In this case, you should probably add a "real" column `sort order` to your tables.